# ngModel not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

```js
$scope.callFunction = function() {
  console.log($scope.modelData);
}
```

```html
<md-select ng-model="modelData" ng-change="callFunction()">
  <md-option ng-repeat="x in tempData" ng-value="x">{{x}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

I'm trying to use the md-select select boxes but the ng-model doesn't seem to work. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

The output in ng-change function comes as undefined.

Comment: my answer is helpful to you ?

Comment: Did you bind it to a controller?

Answer (score 1):

use `$scope.modelData` instead of only `modelData`

```js
$scope.modelData;
$scope.callFunction = function() {
  console.log($scope.modelData);
}
```

```html
<md-select ng-model="modelData" ng-change="callFunction()">
  <md-option ng-repeat="x in tempData" ng-value="x">{{x}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have used $scope in my code and it still doesn't work

Comment: And did you define `$scope.modelData` with your data before? Please share your full code.

Answer (score 1):

the models are accessible  via `$scope` in the controller `$scope.modelName`

```js
// sometime data might not bind for object in that case you to declare this not always 
$scope.modelName;
$scope.callFunction = function() {
  console.log($scope.modelName);
}
```

```html
<md-select ng-model="modelName" ng-change="callFunction()">
  <md-option ng-repeat="x in tempData" ng-value="x">{{x}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it logging `"undefined"`? probably would work better with `console.log($scope.modelData);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add $scope in controller function.

```
 angular.module('test')
    .controller('TestController',['$rootScope','$http','$scope', 
       function ($rootScope,$http, $scope) {
          $scope.callFunction = function() {
            console.log($scope.modelData);
        }
 }])
```